# How to reuse a mysqli_stmt after mysqli::real_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have some scripts working on databases running for a long time (sometimes for hours) and I want to make them as robust as possible.

I have therefore created a
`class extended_mysqli extends mysqli {`
where among other additional functionality I override `query` and add a retry loop and a re-connect (mysqli::real_connect()) in case of loss of connection to the database server.

This works fine with mysqli::query()

I am now tryng to get the same function for prepared statements.
I implemented a subclass
`class extended_mysqli_stmt extends mysqli_stmt {`
In `extended_mysqli` I override the method `prepare()` to return my new class `extended_mysqli_stmt`
In `extended_mysqli_stmt` I override execute() and add mysqli::real_connect() in case of loss of the connection to the database server.

However, even though mysqli::real_connect() is succesful and also mysqli::query() is working, I can not reuse the statement after this it will always return MYSQL error 2006 (MySQL server has gone away).

I tried to use mysqli_stmt::reset(), use mysqli_stmt::free_result(), non of the seems to help.

Here is some of my code:

```
<?php    
class extended_mysqli extends mysqli {

        var $host;
        var $user;
        var $password;
        var $database;

        function __construct($host, $user, $password, $database) {
            $this->host=$host;
            $this->user=$user;
            $this->password=$password;
            $this->database=$database;

            $success=false;
            $retrys = 5;
            $sleep = 3; // seconds

            while (!$success and ($retrys > 0)) {
                parent::__construct($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
                if ($this->connect_errno == 0) {
                    $success = true;
                    }
                else {
                    $retrys--;
                    sleep($sleep);
                    }
                }
            if (!$success) {
                self::report_error('extended_mysqli', $this->connect_errno, $this->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
                }
            }

        public function reconnect() {
            
            $success = false;
            $retrys = 5;
            $sleep = 3; // seconds
            while (!$success and ($retrys > 0)) {
                $this->real_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
                if ($this->connect_errno == 0) {
                    $success = true;
                    }
                else {
                    $retrys--;
                    sleep($sleep);
                    }
                }
            if (!$success) {
                self::report_error('extended_mysqli', $this->connect_errno, $this->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
                }
            }

        #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
        function query(string $query, ?int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT, $ignore_error = false) {
            if (is_null($resultmode)) {  // fixup legacy NULL value
                $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT;
                trigger_error_backtrace("\$resultmode is NULL", E_USER_DEPRECATED);
                }
            $bt = debug_backtrace();
            while (
                !isset($bt[0]['file']) ||
                in_array(basename($bt[0]['file']), [basename(__FILE__), 'class_base.php'])
                ) {
                array_shift($bt);
                }
            foreach (array_reverse($bt) as $caller) {
                if (isset($caller['file'])) {
                    $query = "# QUERY IN {$caller['file']}#{$caller['line']}\n{$query}";
                    }
                }

            // $ignore_error darf entweder ein boolean, ein integer oder ein Array von integers sein
            if (is_int($ignore_error)) {
                $ignore_error = [$ignore_error];
                }

            $success = false;
            $retrys = 10;
            $sleep = 5; // seconds
            $retry_errors = [    // bei diesen Fehlern wird das Query-Kommando noch mal versucht
                1053,   // Server shutdown in progress
                1205,   // Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
                2006,   // MySQL server has gone away
                ];
            $reconnect_errors = [    // bei diesen Fehlern wird das Query-Kommando noch mal versucht
                1053,   // Server shutdown in progress
                2006,   // MySQL server has gone away
                ];
            do {
                $res = parent::query($query, $resultmode);
                $success = !in_array($this->errno, $retry_errors);
                if (!$success) {
                    $retrys--;
                    trigger_error(__FILE__.'#'.__LINE__
                        . " Retry after Database error ({$this->errno}: {$this->error}). {$retrys} Retries left", E_USER_NOTICE);
                    if ($this->errno == 1205) {
                        trigger_error(preg_replace("/(\r|\n)\s*/", ' ', $query));
                        }
                    if (in_array($this->errno, $reconnect_errors)) {
                        sleep($sleep);
                        $this->reconnect();
                        }
                    }
                } while (!$success and ($retrys > 0));
            $this->handle_result($res, $ignore_error);
            return $res;
            }

        #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
        function prepare(string $query, $ignore_error = false) {
            $bt = debug_backtrace();
            while(in_array(basename($bt[0]['file']), [basename(__FILE__), 'class_base.php'])) {
                array_shift($bt);
                }
            foreach (array_reverse($bt) as $caller) {
                if (isset($caller['file'])) {
                    $query = "# PREPARE IN {$caller['file']}#{$caller['line']}\n{$query}";
                    }
                }

            $stmt = new extended_mysqli_stmt($this, $query);
            $this->handle_result($stmt, $ignore_error);
            $stmt->handle_result($ignore_error);
            return $stmt;
            }

        public static function report_error($class, $errno, $error, $error_type = E_USER_ERROR) {
            $error_msg = "Error {$class}: ({$errno}) {$error}";
            $backtrace_error_str = get_error_backtrace($error_msg, __FILE__) . "\n";
            if (display_db_errors) {
                echo nl2br($backtrace_error_str);
                }
            trigger_error($backtrace_error_str, $error_type);
            $f = fopen(__DIR__ . '/var/log/sql_errors.log', 'a');
            fputs($f, '[' . date('d-M-Y H:i:s') . '] ' . $backtrace_error_str);
            fclose($f);
            }

        private function handle_result($res, $ignore_error) {
            if (!$res and
                   (($ignore_error === false)
                       or (is_array($ignore_error) and !in_array($this->errno, $ignore_error))
                       )
                   ) {
                self::report_error('extended_mysqli', $this->errno, $this->error);
                }
            }

        }


    class extended_mysqli_stmt extends mysqli_stmt {

        public function execute(?array $params = null): bool {
            global $db;

            $success = false;
            $retrys = 10;
            $sleep = 5; // seconds
            $retry_errors = [    // bei diesen Fehlern wird der Execute noch mal versucht
                1053,   // Server shutdown in progress
                1205,   // Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
                2006,   // MySQL server has gone away
                ];
            $reconnect_errors = [    // bei diesen Fehlern wird zuvor 5sec gewartet und die Verbindung zum DB-Server neu aufgebaut
                1053,   // Server shutdown in progress
                2006,   // MySQL server has gone away
                ];
            do {
                //$res = parent::execute($params);   
                // führt zu
                // Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::execute() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given
                // ?????
                
                $res = parent::execute();
                $success = !in_array($this->errno, $retry_errors);
                if (!$success) {
                    $retrys--;
                    trigger_error(__FILE__ . '#' . __LINE__
                        . " Retry after Database error ({$this->errno}: {$this->error}). {$retrys} Retries left", E_USER_NOTICE);
                    if (in_array($this->errno, $reconnect_errors)) {
                        sleep($sleep);
                        $db->reconnect();
                        }
                    }
                } while (!$success and ($retrys > 0));
            if (!$res) {
                extended_mysqli::report_error('extended_mysqli_stmt', $this->errno, $this->error);
                }
            return $res;
            }

        public function handle_result($ignore_error) {
            if ($this->errno and
                   (($ignore_error === false)
                       or (is_array($ignore_error) and !in_array($this->errno, $ignore_error))
                       )
                   ) {
                       extended_mysqli::report_error('extended_mysqli_stmt', $this->errno, $this->error);
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: you have to re-prepare as well

Comment: On a side note, `var` was the syntax to declare class properties back in PHP/4. It still works, but it's a syntax that was superseded in 2004.

Comment: @YourCommonSense To re-prepare was the first step to the solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Override mysqli_stmt::__construct and mysqli_stmt::bind_param and store the query and the params to properties

```
public function __construct(mysqli $mysql, ?string $query = null) {
    parent::__construct($mysql, $query);
    $this->last_query = $query;
}        

public function bind_param(string $types, mixed &...$vars): bool {
    $this->bind_param_types = $types;
    $this->bind_param_vars = $vars;
    return parent::bind_param($types, ...$vars);
}
```

In extended_mysqli_stmt::execute() add the following code after the reconnect of the mysqli-Object:

```
$db->reconnect();
$this->close();
parent::__construct($db, $this->last_query);
parent::bind_param($this->bind_param_types, ...$this->bind_param_vars);
```

I feel a bit uneasy to call the parent constructer for an existing object instance. I did not find any other working solution.